# Caching vs Database Query

Tags: mysql, database, performance, file, caching

I've searched this question over the internet but i've never found a real good answer from an web veteran. The question is:

What method delivers the best performance? Database querying or Disk Caching?

Let's take an online shop platform for example, is it better to always query the products or is it better to cache them as files and only recache when needed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you find out when a recache is need. So you can use the Query-Cache from MySQL and it handles it for you

Comment: For example, when a product its edited it will be automatically marked for recache.

Comment: There are many things for recache. Edit the product, price change, stock change, delivery time

Comment: Agree, but isn't that faster than always querying the product(s) for every visitor?

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to cache it. So you can the hole html block for a product. so its not necessary to render this again. You can store it in ramdisc or memcache

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

- A poorly optimized query can be so slow that it needs help -- but adding an index might be all it needs.
- For rapidly changing things, any kind of cache needs purging/updating.  The MySQL's Query cache takes care of such, but that often leads to making the QC useless.
- Running a `SELECT` often does not have to touch disk; this gives it a *potential* advantage over your "Disk Caching".

Bottom Line:  There is no "one size fits all".  Build your system without any caching, then work on speeding up things *where* needed.  You will probably find that caching is "more trouble than it is worth".  Or at least that has been my experience.

Comment: Thank you for your post, i will definetly consider your advice.